# New ASP.NET Core project has random attribute added to elements

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have created a new ASP.NET Core project with Visual Studio 2022.  I've run the application and looked at the source of the home page.  Several of the elements from the _Layout page have a random attribute added.

Here's a snippet of the generated html when the application is running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home page - WebApplication1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?v=AKvNjO3dCPPS0eSU1Ez8T2wI280i08yGycV9ndytL-c" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/WebApplication1.styles.css?v=bORd7i_49MmkY_u045aCr39djituvpXrqrsQ_3TezVg" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav b-g6ltozs93r class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div b-g6ltozs93r class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">WebApplication1</a>
                <button b-g6ltozs93r class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span b-g6ltozs93r class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div b-g6ltozs93r class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul b-g6ltozs93r class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li b-g6ltozs93r class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li b-g6ltozs93r class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Notice the **b-g6ltozs93r** in several of the elements.  This is not in the source!

The source for the HTML above from _Layout.cshtml is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/WebApplication1.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">WebApplication1</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Why is that random attribute being added!?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes that other question is the same.  And the answer on that fixed the issue.  Thanks!!!